# How to write and save each line separately on a txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, dynamic, writefile

I'm running two .py files. One creates one random float number between 1 and 10 and then writes it in a file. 
The other one is plotting these numbers. My animation is working fine as I write and "save", but with the automation of writing process, data only get saved as I stop the program, and the file.close() takes action (outside my looping).

I've tried putting the .open and .close() inside the looping, but this way it only saves the last line I wrote, and I still need to pause the program.

writer code:

```
import random
import time


i=0
with open('datatest.txt', 'w') as a:
    while True:
        line = str(i) + ',' + str(random.uniform(1,10)) + '\n'
        a.write(line)
        print(line)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(9)
```

graphic animation code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    print("inside animate")
    pullData = open("data.txt","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []

    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(float(x))
            yar.append(float(y))

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,yar)

    plt.xlabel('Hora')
    plt.ylabel('Valor Dado')
    plt.title('Pseudo-Sensor x Hora')


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000) 
plt.show()
```

I was expecting to view 'live action' of the writing process being saved on my txt file, so my graph would refresh as each saving step would run.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file in append mode everytime

```
while True:    
    with open('datatest.txt', 'a+') as a:
        line = str(i) + ',' + str(random.uniform(1,10)) + '\n'
        a.write(line)
        print(line)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(9)
```

Comment: This is working like a charm. It has a bit of delay (seems like he saves line x once he writes line x+1), but this is already giving me live fed graph.

Thank you very much, Akhil!